# How to restrict an enum to only its members

Tags: typescript

```
export enum BASE_ROUTES {
  MODULES = 'modules',
  RESULTS = 'results',
  ISSUES = 'issues',
  FINISH = 'finish',
  NEWSLETTER = 'newsletter',
  REWARDS = 'rewards'
}
```

Currently (unless I misconfigured something) I am allowed to access things beyond what the enum above described. I can, for example, do `BASE_ROUTES.foo`. Is there a way I can generate a warning and make this a restricted enum?

Context: I am accessing the enum in a `js` file (in the middle of a refactor where we support both `ts` and `js`).

What I see: [image: code]

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: actually you're supposed to get this error. TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'typeof BASE_ROUTES'.

Comment: Ah, woops I forgot to add the necessary context. I am accessing the enum in a js file

Comment: I believe type checking related features are only available in ts & tsx. Enums are not supported in JavaScript natively.

Comment: Is there any way to only have typechecking for .ts ending imports? Obviously I don't want my entire js file to be checked, as there would be a lot of "no implicit anys" etc noise

Comment: Since JS don't support enum, this feature won't be available in a js file. Try changing enum to object with Object.freeze({key: value}), maybe you'll get warning if code editor detects missing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you want to migrate to Typescript, you better convert all your `.js` files to `.ts` since Typescript is simply a superset of JS and valid JS is still valid in TS.

I saw in comments that you mentioned:

> Obviously I don't want my entire js file to be checked, as there would
> be a lot of "no implicit anys" etc noise

In order to do so, you just need to set `noImplicitAny` property to false in your `tsconfig` file. like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // other options
  "noImplicitAny": false,
}
```

Later when you had time to type implicit anys in your fiiles, you can set it true. Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) for more information.

Comment: can I make it such that that option is only present for files ending in `js`?

Comment: @ParthianShotgun I'm not sure if I can understand what you're asking correctly. but Typescript rules and type-checking (and all compiler options specified in `tsconfig`) are applied only to `.ts` files, Typescript doesn't check `.js` files at all.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess a more refined question would be, is there a way I typecheck javascript files, but only check if the thing that it imports its a typescript file. To get the benefits of autocomplete and underlining (like when I have the `checkJs` flag set to true, but not be too cumbersome

Comment: @ParthianShotgun I don't think so. But as I said, valid JS is valid in TS, so you only need to change file extensions and then config your `tsconfig` as strict or loose as you want.